# Search style in Napilli

Tags: lightning, customer-community, napili, lightning-community

I'm trying to create a theme for Napili with a custom search bar, I am following the docs: [Create Custom Search and Profile Menu Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm). But when I type something to search, the page does not show results. These component works with something like lightning events? or something similar that I'm not using?

Code:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" access="global">
            <div class="search">
                <div class="search-wrapper">
                    <form class="search-form">
                        <div class="search-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="My Search"/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I could recommend a free AppExchange package to modify the search in the comunity

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009x8GjEAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this making a redirection to the search page with the appended search string, I think that is not the best way but, its working.

Example: `/<commName>/s/search/All/Home/<searchString>`